# C# Linq-to-SQL Not Updating After Ado.net Insert

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I've created a 1:many relationship and bulk inserts I make via ADO.net aren't propagating to my LINQ-to-SQL data context.

e.g.

```
TABLE School
  int schoolId
  int maxStudents
  ...

TABLE Students
  int studentId
  int schoolId
  DateTime birthdate
  ...
```

If I bulk add, say, 500 students to the `Students` table, my data context doesn't update .Students.  It just says .Students.Count() == 0.

**EDIT**  Here's an example:

```
// Create a Repository
Repository Repo = new Repository();
string[] schoolNames = GetSchoolNames();

// Pull in the schools.
IEnumerable<School> schools = Repo.GetSchools(schoolNames);
foreach (School school in schools) school.DoSomeDirectDBWork();
schoolNames = schools.Select(school => school.name).ToArray();
Repo.Dispose();  // Flush/Close/Dispose

Repo = new Repository();  // New repository, new data context.
schools = Repo.GetSchools(schoolNames);
// ** THE SCHOOLS HAVE NO STUDENTS AT THIS POINT IN THE CODE.
// ** <SAD FACE>
```

Comment: Please show the code where you're doing the inserts.

Comment: @sgtz LINQ-to-SQL = SQL server unless you are doing bad things

Comment: Correct, this is LINQ-to-SQL with an MS-SQL back end.  The ADO.net provider is stitching a _gigantic_ INSERT statement, so it wouldn't be practical to put it here.  Just imagine a typical multi-insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is simply cacheing. If you have forced it to load an unfiltered set of students, then sure - it might well the trust that set (empty at the point of load). DataContext is intended to be short-lived; try creating a new one after the insert and retry. If this hasn't already read the empty table it should find your data.

Additionally, check you don't have two Students tables - for example dbo.Students vs bluesummers.Students.

Comment: You're correct, sir!  I held on to the parent object's ID (in this case `<School>.schoolId` and re-pulled the school with another data context, and the counts were updated.

Comment: Strange; a little while later I ran into this problem again, but it's much worse.  I can't seem to get it to update the stock object- even after creating an entirely new data context and attempting to re-pull the `<School>` object.